# Is there an equivalent to the Mac OS X software Hazel?

Tags: software-recommendation, mac, macosx

Is there an equivalent to the Mac OS X software [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) that runs on Ubuntu?

> "Hazel watches whatever folders you tell it to, automatically
>   organizing your files according to the rules you create. It features a
>   rule interface [..]. Have Hazel move files around based on name, date,
>   type, what site/email address it came from [..] and much more.
>   Automatically put your music in your Music folder, movies in Movies.
>   Keep your downloads off the desktop and put them where they are
>   supposed to be."

This question probably won't make sense unless you have used Hazel, but basically you can define rules via the GUI to move and rename files automatically to make an automated workflow.

Comment: Glad you guys like Maid.  I just released v0.6.0 that has "watch" support, bringing Maid a little closer to Hazel.  Check out the project for details:  https://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use maid : http://alternativeto.net/software/maid/
Love it, keeps everything as clean as if I had a, well, maid!

Answer (score 4):

You can install [Maid](http://rubygems.org/gems/maid) in Ubuntu as follows:

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y ruby1.9.1 rubygems; sudo gem install maid`

For more info (such as how to write rules), [look at the projects README](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid/blob/master/README.md).